# Negation of sequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just to verify that the negation of sequence convergence of ($a_n$) to a limit, a would be something like:

"There exists a $ \epsilon >0$ s.t. for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $n> \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|a_n-a|\geq\epsilon$"

Is this right?  My instructor wrote as a hint that we should start off by excluding all real numbers as limits.  I don't quite understand what he means by that.  Can someone give me a hint or clarify this?

Comment: I think you mean $|a_n - a| > \epsilon$, right? Assuming so, then you have negated the statement that $a_n$ converges to the specific limit $a$. It sounds like your instructor wants you to negate the statement that $a_n$ converges to *any* limit. To do that, your negation will be almost the same, except you will start by saying "Given any real number $a$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$..."

Comment: So if I understand what you are saying, is it just adding the line "Given any real number a" before my negated statement?

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote "there exists an $n > \mathbb{N}$", which makes no sense. I think you meant to say "for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $n > N$ such that..." By the way, an equivalent way to express this is: "There exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|a_n - a| \geq \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of the above statement would be $\exists \epsilon_o>0$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}~\exists p>k $ such that $$|a_p-a|\geq \epsilon_0$$